# Wildfly - How to startup bean before persistence is loaded?

Tags: java, jpa, ejb, ear, wildfly

I would like to execute some logic before Persistence Unit is loaded in Wildfly 8.0.
I have a structure like this:

- xxx.ear

  - before-persistence-bean.jar
  - beans.jar
  - xxx.war

beans.jar contains entity beans with persistence.XML and session beans

before-persistence-bean.jar contains one class:

```
@Startup
@Singleton
public class BeforePersistenceServiceBean {

    @PostConstruct
    public void performOperations() {...}

}
```

In application.xml I have:

```
<initialize-in-order>true</initialize-in-order>
<module>
    <ejb>before-persistence-bean.jar</ejb>
</module>
<module>
    <ejb>beans.jar</ejb>
</module>
<module>
    <web>
        <web-uri>xxx.war</web-uri>
        <context-root>/xxx</context-root>
    </web>
</module>
```

Now, after starting Wildfly I get error that:

```
service jboss.persistenceunit."xxx.ear/beans.jar#pu_name" (missing) dependents: 
[service jboss.deployment.subunit."xxx.ear"."before-persistence
bean.jar".component.BeforePersistenceServiceBean.START]
```

But BeforePersistenceServiceBean doesn't have dependency on Persistence Unit, what is going on here ?

**---EDIT---**

After failing to deploy this bean before persistence kicks off, I have used solution
similar to described in [CDI Extension for Flyway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11071821/cdi-extension-for-flyway) (i.e. using Hibernate Integrator API)

Comment: Are you able to provide snippet of the code? It will help to debug it

Comment: The method performOperations is actually empty (for now), just testing possible solution to execute something before persistence unit is deployed

Answer (score 1):

Add a `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` to the `META-INF` directory if your EAR to indicate you want the [subdeployments isolated](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Class+Loading+in+WildFly#ClassLoadinginWildFly-EARClassLoading).

I would imagine the contents would look something like

```xml
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:1.0" >            
  <ear-subdeployments-isolated>false</ear-subdeployments-isolated>
  <sub-deployment name="xxx.war">
    <dependencies>
      <module name="deployment.xxx.ear.beans.jar" />
    </dependencies>
  </sub-deployment>
</subsystem>
```

Comment: It haven't helped, whether ear-subdeployments-isolated is set to true or false - same problem (service jboss.persistenceunit."xxx.ear/beans.jar#pu_name" (missing))

Comment: I would assume the answer is yes, but does your beans.jar use JPA?

Comment: yes, as I said, beans.jar contains entity beans with JPA persistence.xml, but before-persistence-bean.jar doesn't have dependency neither on beans.jar nor JPA

Comment: No, nothing more in error message, just dependecy missing... I've found antoher solution as described in EDIT section of the question, thanks